# Object Tracking Based off of Segmentation

Tags: opencv, vision

I have an algorithm that gives me the segmentation mask of an object. It works well but is a little slow. I was wondering if there is a tracking algorithm where the input is a mask (or the contours of said previous mask) along with obviously the new image. I know optical flow and all the shift algorithms could track movement which I could then try to reconstruct the objects mask, but the object could rotate which would make the above algorithms less precise. The idea would be run the first algorithm once, and then run the tracking algorithm after.

Comment: is the background static in this scenario or does the camera move?

Comment: The background can be assumed to be static

Comment: Then try [https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html](background subtraction)